# Unexcpected NULL result with SELECT CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, case, aggregate-functions

The following is my query:

```
DECLARE
    @ThisYear INT = CAST(DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) AS INT) 
    ,@LastYear INT = CAST(DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) - 1 AS INT)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN CAST(DATEPART(yy, mq.[qDate]) AS INT)   = @ThisYear THEN 5
            WHEN CAST(DATEPART(yy, mq.[qDate]) - 1 AS INT) = @LastYear THEN 6 END AS 'TimePeriodID'
    ,Name = 'QueryTotals'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN dQuery = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DefaultQuery'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN dQuery = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Non-DefaultQuery'
    ,COUNT(dQuery) AS 'TotalQueries'
FROM 
    mQuery mq
INNER JOIN 
    mParameter mp
    ON
    mq.id = mp.id
INNER JOIN 
    Variable v
    ON
    mp.id = v.id
WHERE 
    v.id <= 10
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN CAST(DATEPART(yy, mq.[qDate]) AS INT)   = @ThisYear THEN 5
            WHEN CAST(DATEPART(yy, mq.[qDate]) - 1 AS INT) = @LastYear THEN 6 END
```

The following is a screenshot of my results:

[image]

Please disregard rows with `TimePeriodID = 1, 2, 3, 4` as these were `UNION`ed to the query stated in question.

Why am I getting a `NULL` in TimePeriodID when it should be `6`?

Please note that the resulting totals are correct and there are dates in the table with dates that satisfy the condition to be `6`.

I am at a loss with this.

An extra eye would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combination of statements:

```
DECLARE
    @ThisYear INT = CAST(DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) AS INT) 
    ,@LastYear INT = CAST(DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) - 1 AS INT)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN CAST(DATEPART(yy, mq.[qDate]) AS INT)   = @ThisYear THEN 5
            WHEN CAST(DATEPART(yy, mq.[qDate]) - 1 AS INT) = @LastYear THEN 6 END AS 'TimePeriodID'
```

makes it impossible for the 2nd case to ever be true. If the first cast != @ThisYear, then the second cast (which is the 1st - 1) can't be == @LastYear, becuase @LastYear = @ThisYear - 1.

So That's the reason. The solution is unclear because you didn't show what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Sir!  This was driving me nuts.  Changed to:  `CASE YEAR(mq.[qDate]) WHEN @ThisYear THEN 5
   WHEN @LastYear THEN 6 END AS 'TimePeriodID'`  and works.  I knew it was something elementary.